# AlphaBot, which type of 18650

Tags: battery

The [AlphaBot](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33000669195.html?fbclid=IwAR3WD0xXL8b4EPpX0VXlbbB5VnhLLuO37L-wf7WW3QriKsOGOA_jdtm-fAo) uses batteries 18650.

But does anyone know if it should be the ones with the button top or the flat top?

Heres a button top:
[https://www.amazon.com/AllForBest-Protected-Panasonic-18650-Battery-Flashlight/dp/B0821SRZ31/ref=sr_1_1?crid=370I0UOE79SVT&keywords=panasonic+18650+battery+button+top&qid=1576283559&sprefix=panasonoic+18650+battery%2Caps%2C247&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0821SRZ31)

And heres a flat top:
[https://www.amazon.com/Authentic-Rechargeable-Replacement-18650-LG-Battery-Flashlight/dp/B07YWRYZL4/ref=sr_1_8?crid=370I0UOE79SVT&keywords=panasonic+18650+battery+button+top&qid=1576283559&sprefix=panasonoic+18650+battery%2Caps%2C247&sr=8-8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YWRYZL4)

How does one find information like this out? I've been looking through all the AlphaBot catalogues, electric shops, asking electricians, electric store clerks, google, raspberry pi fb chat groups and whatnot and nobody seems to know this.

To put this into a context, I have already wasted $150 purchasing 18650 batteries, only to find out they are not the version of 18650 batteries that are fitting. This time I really want to purchase the correct type of 18650 batteries. The other time I purchased 18650 batteries for the AlphaBot in a vape shop, only to find out that they are slightly too large for the AlphaBot.

Apparently 18650 is not the same as 18650.

Comment: I thought 18650 has only one size, fitting all 18650 cases: 
(1) https://www.waveshare.com/alphabot-pi.htm
(2) https://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/alphabot-basic-robot-platform-kit-User-Manual.pdf
(3) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes#Lithium-ion_batteries_(rechargeable)

Comment: where do you see that in those links?

Comment: there are two types of 18650. flat and with hat on top. And i don't know which one to use.

Comment: It would help if we had links to the batteries that are confusing you. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by a "hat." Are you referring a "bulge" like on a AA battery for the positive terminal?

Comment: i have now found out that its called "button top" and "flat top". i have updated the information.

Comment: @Hermann Ingjaldsson, My apologies. I though there is no big deal. I was VERY WRONG! :((1) Flat Topped vs Button-Topped, what's the deal? - candlepowerforums
https://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?312551-Flat-Topped-vs-Button-Topped-what-s-the-deal

(2) Battery, button or flat top
https://lygte-info.dk/info/Battery%20button%20or%20flat%20UK.html

(2) 18650 battery test 2011 - 
http://lygte-info.dk/info/Batteries18650-2011%20UK.html.  Cheers

Comment: Can you see there, which type I should be using for the AlphaBot? I skimmed through those articles and couldn't find that.

Answer (score 2):

All the *individual* 18650s I have ever seen have a 'hat' on one side, and are flat on the other. This prevents the batteries from being accidentally installed backwards.
When in doubt, put the battery in like you would a AA battery. The spring in the holder goes to the flat side of the battery, and the hat side goes to the flat side of the battery holder.

Now I have heard of 18650s that are flat on both ends, but I think they are solely for battery banks like this where space is at a premium.[image]

Comment: This indicates flat ones should not be considered for the AlphaBot. But I have another user saying "I do not recommend buying batteries with a hat on the top". So its all in the air.

Comment: If you still aren't sure you could just buy both kinds and see which one fits.

Comment: But again all the kits I've seen have the one-way batteries.